# Drupal: Retrieve and print a node name (not type)

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views, drupal-blocks

I’ve a block, created in the views module, where I post the most recent comments made by a user (e.g. the five most recent comments for user uid 1033). I’ve created my own tpl file so I can customize which fields I want to display and it works.

It prints the first 140 characters of the comment and link to the node with the #cid behind it.

But underneath that I want to show which node-type it is posted in. I tried by using this code:
`print $node->type;`
but that – of cause – just prints the node type and that is not especially human readable so what I want is the node name (from the database class “node_type”) but I just can’t get my head around how to do that.

Is there any easy way or do I have to use some kind of customized query / API call??

Comment: If you don't get an answer here, perhaps try on http://drupal.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at node_get_types() api function.

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/node_get_types/6

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the Node:Type field inside the view?

Answer (score 0):

Unless your are doing something really wrong such as doing a full node_load() of each in your .tpl.php file, you need to configure your view to display the node type. Templates aren't mean to add additional data but only format and layout their display.

In order to display the type of the node a comment is attached to, you need to

1. Add a relationship to the node
2. Configure the *Row style* to use *Fields* rows style
3. Add the *Node: Type* to the displayed Fields

[image: screenshot of the view configuration]